# Using segues for programmatically constructed tableview cells

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am avoiding the use of static prototype cells in storyboards mode of interface builder. But I still want to use segues when those cells are pressed to display the detail view controller.

I tried to create a segue in IB but it's not letting me (dragging on from the tableview itself) so I went ahead and tried programmatic created as follows:

```
[[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"FriendProfileSegue" source:self destination:[[BBFOtherProfileController alloc] init]];
```

However I still get a crash because the destination view controller doesn't have the segue implemented. Any way around this problem? I'd prefer to create the segue in IB, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make a segue in IB easily: Hold Control and click on the table view cell, then drag to the destination view controller. Make sure you are actually clicking on the table view cell and not a sub view within it. To make sure, you can select the table view cell in the left side panel first, then control-click and drag from it in the diagram view.

Usually, if you aren't using IB to create your segues, you just do the thing the regular old way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```